# Bulk API Relationships

Tags: rest-api, relationships

I am getting mixed signals on if you can use relationships with the BULK api.

**I am calling** /services/async/{{0}}/job/{0}/batch/{1} with a API

I have a Certification(Custom Object) object that is child to a Contact(Standard Object)  which has a CustomerID__c as the externalID .  I would like to use the externalID as the key to relate the two objects as Child-parent relationships with the following JSON.

> [[{"CustomerEventCertificationDetailID__c":"952263","Certification_Type__c":"Hunter Education","Contact":{"CustomerID__c":"24877"},"Certification_Number__c":"85031880","Certification_State__c":"LA","attributes":null}]]

But I am getting **"Records not processed"** not sure how to fix that

https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/api_asynch.pdf on page 21 talks about this being possible but I don't see it working

```
[{
"Name" : "CustomObject1",
"Mother_Of_Child__r" : { "External_ID__c" : "123456" }
}]
```

I have seen rumors that the API doesn't match the documentation can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: The blog is based on the official [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_xml_rel_fields.htm), the doc is still correct afaik. If you edit your question and provide more details on these two custom objects and the bulk API method you're trying to use, it would help. For example, your `ContactPerson` might be referring to a [Person Account](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_person.htm&type=5) but it's unclear.

Comment: updated... Thank you for your help

Comment: `/services/async/{{0}}/job/{0}/batch/{1}` is adding a batch to a job via Bulk API v1. The [API call requires a CSV](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_quickstart_add_batch.htm) and your question shows JSON, perhaps start there. You're using an older version of Bulk API. It's still available but v2 is a preferred route and there's a [tutorial on v2](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_bulk)

Comment: I have other calls that are working with JSON just fine. I don't think its having trouble parsing. But maybe

Comment: Thank you for your help as I am learning more I am realizing you were correct.